# Making custom site wide tokens

Tags: 8, tokens

I'm attempting to add a custom token so I can use it in a view block. Looking at examples I've added this code to my custom .theme file

```
function mytheme_token_info(){
  $types['mytheme_tokens'] = [
    'name' => t('mytheme Tokens'),
    'description' => t('mytheme token type'),
  ];
  $currentnode_token['current_node_title'] = [
    'name' => t('Current Node Title'),
    'description' => t('Title of the current node'),
  ];
  return [
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => [
      'mytheme_tokens' => $currentnode_token,
    ],
  ];
}
function mytheme_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata){
  $token_service = \Drupal::token();
  $replacements = array();
  if($type == 'mytheme_tokens') {
    foreach($tokens as $name => $original){
      switch($name){
        case 'current_node_title':
        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
        $title = (!empty($node)) ? $node->title->value : ''; 
        $replacements[$original] = $title;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```

But in my view in a custom text block I have a header using that token but it spits out

> ## [mytheme_tokens:current_node_title] Products

And the token isn't replaced. I know for sure the tokenizer is running though because [site:title] did work.

How do you create custom globally available tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes can only implement alter, theme and pre/process hooks.

Re-implement those hooks in a custom module and they should work fine.